# NTFS vs ext4 for reliability

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, filesystems

The reason for this question has to do with recent behaviour of a NTFS 1TB external drive I rely on for important production.

Since I work both on Linux and Windows (although primarily Linux-Ubuntu) I reasoned that NTFS made the most sense for compatibility reasons.
However recently have experienced strange behavior.
On windows a large folder would not open and then a couple days later the entire drive would not mount on my Linux desktop.

Ran chkdsk in Windows to repair the filesystem but I am wondering if NTFS is a good idea if I need reliability over convenience?

Comment: If you need to share/use the drive in Windows and Linux then NTFS is indeed the option that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking a wrong question.

If you want to protect against data loss (due to drive failure, malware, loss of power, user error etc.) the solution is to **make backups**. No filesystem is bulletproof. If you can't afford losing your data, make backups. As the old adage says:

> There are two kinds of people: those who make backups, and those who will.

If you want to protect against downtime caused by drive failure, go for a NAS with two identical capacity disks in RAID1. Capacity of only one drive will be available. If any drive fails, NAS will alert you about this and you'll still be able to access your data on the second drive. Then you can replace the faulty one and NAS will rebuild it from the good one (takes between a few hours and a couple of days, performance will be degraded during this time).

Please note that RAID is not a backup. As the newer adage says:

> If malware deletes all your files, RAID will make sure to delete all copies.

For full protection against data loss and downtime you need both reliable, known-good-and-restorable backups and RAID.

Answer (score 1):

For my network I use Samba (cifs) shares from Ubuntu machines mounting ext drives.  This allows me to interact with the drives via ssh or directly on the Ubuntu machine and I get all the benefits of ext.  It also allows me to mount those drives via smb using either Windows or Ubuntu and suffer the limitations associated therewith (minor as they may be).  Further, since Win10 now includes the Subsystem for Linux and I can install Ubuntu (and bash) into Win10 where I can use ssh for interacting there as well.

If you are in a dual-boot situation, you are rather stuck using NTFS and suffering its inherent limitations (I'm looking at you, colon and question mark prohibition) or worse using exFAT and suffering its greater limitations.

Answer (score -1):

NTFS is not considered to be a resilient file system, it only journals metadata and suffers from bit rot, which is made worse by the fragmentation it also suffers from.

The most reliable file systems feature Copy on Write (CoW) and data integrity mechanisms, for example the new [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) and the modern [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) both have these as default features, even on single disks. Particularly, APFS writes changes to existing files in new locations, whereas other file systems overwrite existing blocks which wear out the disk sectors on flash storage and create a moment where the original file and the new file are both incomplete- leading to data loss during an error or power failure. ZFS on the other hand has the highest quantity and most impressive data integrity mechanisms in place as it is a core focus of the file system.

As Gronostaj pointed out, RAID is indeed the best available option for data integrity. However, I would suggest using ZFS software RAID over other software options such as Windows Software RAID or Linux Software RAID. Additionally, if you choose to go with hardware RAID, [do not use RAID5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Weaknesses) as it is deprecated and susceptible to bit rot. Note that all hardware RAID types and standard software RAID types have weaknesses, even ZFS is susceptible to a poor deployment or multiple drive failures but the odds are far lower with ZFS.

For an overview of ZFS, consider reading [this article](https://itsfoss.com/what-is-zfs/). For a technical description of ZFS, consider reading the [Wikipedia article on OpenZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS).